# Use Sketch-RNN model (from tensorflow/magenta) with Sketch-RNN-JS

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, magenta

I'm currently playing around with [Sketch-RNN-JS](http://Sketch-RNN-JS). But instead of using the pre-trained models from Quick Draw (like described in the readme of the project) I was trying to train my own model with [magenta's Sketch-RNN](https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/tree/master/magenta/models/sketch_rnn).
The result of this training process (`sketch_rnn_train`) is a data directory with the model consisting of several vector- `.data-00000-of-00001`, `.index` and `.meta` files, and a `model_config.json` (apparently documenting my configuration).

What I'm missing is the step of converting this model into a format Sketch-RNN-JS can work with (apparently a `JSON` file like [this](https://storage.googleapis.com/quickdraw-models/sketchRNN/large_models/spider.vae.json)). Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?